# SVN delete --keep-local

Tags: svn

I'm working on a project where someone has checked in some folders and files that are not suppose to be in the repository and are suppose to be on our local, I try to delete them by the following command and it gives me this error

```
svn delete filename --keep-local
svn: invalid option: --keep-local
```

Comment: Which version of SVN do you have?  --keep-local was only added in a later version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Upgrade to the [latest version of the SVN client](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/). The version you have installed doesn't have the `--keep-local` option yet. This feature was [added in SVN 1.5](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#cmdline).

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you have the latest version of Tortoise or Ankh, that doesn't upgrade your command-line client.  :)

Comment: is there something like --keep-local in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: found it: SHIFT+RightClick opens the extended menu containing Delete (keep local)

Answer (score 13):

Please note that `delete --keep-local` only keeps the deleted files/folders in **your** local working copy.

When your coworkers perform their next `update`, the affected files/folders will be deleted in their working copies.

The `keep-local` option isn't as useful as a lot of people seem to think it is.

Comment: There are times that it is actually helpful. For instance, on linux svn ignores changes to file permissions after the initial commit of the file. This can be frustrating if you have a shell script that you forgot to mark executable. I will delete svn's copy while keeping my local version, ensure that I have the permissions I want set are correct, then svn add the file back into version control and the shell script is permanently executable.

Answer (score 6):

[As wcoenen and Dave Markle said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281028/svn-delete-keep-local/2281036#2281036), you have an old version that doesn't have the `--keep-local` option.  To be more specific, this option was introduced in version 1.5.

As a workaround:

1. Copy the files out of your working copy
2. `svn delete`
3. `svn commit`
4. Copy them back into the working copy
5. Add them to `svn:ignore` so they don't get checked in again!

Comment: I've given this a +1 because even with the keep-local option, I still had trouble deleting a few years of incorrectly added binary files from my repository. Using keep-local and svn:ignore just caused my files to be deleted completely - I still needed to keep them, I just didn't want them in my repository :)