# Why SVN is not ignoring files

Tags: svn

my SVN setting says that I am ignoring following files

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db *.classpath .classpath *.project .project logs .log
```

but it is actually not ignoring and still showing .classpath and .project in the list of modified file. Is there any way I can ignore them permanently. 
[image]

Comment: When you say "modified", that implies to me that the files are currently versioned (stored in the repository). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, those file are stored in the repository. Should I remove them from there ?

Answer (score 2):

Once an item is versioned (stored in the repository), it cannot be ignored. If you want to ignore these items:

1. Copy them to a safe place
2. `svn delete` them
3. Commit the change
4. Copy the files back

Other option: [`svn delete —keep-local`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281036)

The files can now be ignored.